# Angular 2+: Angular way of breaking down large component.ts file

Tags: angular, angular5, organization, code-organization, readability

This question pertains to code organization. 
I am the author of an Angular package called ng-simple-slideshow. By far the longest file is the [component.ts](https://github.com/dockleryxk/ng-simple-slideshow/blob/master/src/app/modules/slideshow/slideshow.component.ts) file of the slideshow. It's so long that it's becoming hard to read.

What would be the angular way of separating this code for organization and readability?

Answer (score 1):

When I design classes with angular 2+, I use concepts from Object Oriented Programming languages, such as Java. Inheritance, Encapsulation, Polymorphism, and Abstraction (The 4 PILLARS of java).

I try to design my classes to focus on a single purpose.

Using Inheritance and Composite based designs to provide code: reusability, readability, and loose coupling between classes.

Project tree structure, naming your classes / files are important too. If done right, it can provide a high-level view of what is already available in your codebase, and make it easier for others to use it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The thing is, for this particular use there is no need for this class to be used again. It's a simple package and this is the only component.